# Cannot mount volumes inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have this docker compose in my repo

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  service:
    image: <REGISTRIY_LINK_TO_IMG>
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8081:8081"

  gql-schema-verify:
    image: <REGISTRIY_LINK_TO_IMG>
    entrypoint: []
    volumes:
      - ./service/src/main/resources/graphql:/home/node/updated
    environment:
      - VALIDATED_SERVICE=core
    command: /bin/bash validate
```

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
validate_schema:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: package
  image: <REGISTRIY_LINK_TO_IMG>
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: <REGISTRIY_LINK_TO_IMG>
  before_script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set region $AWS_REGION
    - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_REGION --no-include-email)
    - echo "AWS login ok"
    - echo "Getting the latest short commit hash for API GQL GW"
    - apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y jq 
  script:
    - docker-compose -p $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG up --build -d service
    - sh ./docker-build-check.sh "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}_service_1" 70

    # Additional debug output
    - echo "Listing contents of ./service/src/main/resources/graphql:"
    - ls -la ./service/src/main/resources/graphql

    # schema check
    - docker-compose -p $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG run --rm verify-gql

  after_script: # docker cleanup
    - docker-compose -p $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG rm --stop -v --force
  tags:
    - internal-docker-dind
```

What is not working is that, even tho the `# Additional debug output` shows the right files ...

```bash
$ ls -la ./service/src/main/resources/graphql
total 24
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Feb 23 15:47 .
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Feb 15 19:00 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            17 Feb 10 18:34 test.graphqls
```

However -the `/home/node/updated` ... it's empty

On the schema check (last step in the script) ... this is the verify-gql

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ls -la /home/node/updated
```

the ls -la shows empty directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 23 15:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 node node 4096 Feb 23 18:08 ..
```

Any idea why??

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted runner or a shared runner on gitlab.com? If you're self-hosting your runner, can you tell me if you have any "volumes" specified in its configuration? (especially if you're mounting `/var/run/docker.sock`)

Comment: @sytech yes I do have self-hosted runners and yes I am mounting  `/var/run/docker.sock`  ... >> `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]`

Comment: So. The basic problem is that you're (probably) using the host docker daemon. You can run `docker info` to see for sure. You probably want to be using the `docker:dind` container for your docker daemon instead and not the host daemon. When binding the host's docker socket, your bind volume mounts will not make any sense, because it's referring to the host's filesystem, not the container filesystem. If my suspicion is correct, you should be able to fix this by setting the environment variables `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375` `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` and (optionally) removing the socket volume.

Comment: @sytech thx a bunch :) that DID work .. can you put it as an asnwer pls? so I can tag it as a correct one? btw the removing of the socket volume was not optional.. it didn't work until I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this circumstance is that your runner configuration has the host's docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) mounted into the job container. Your job is using this socket rather than the `docker:dind` service. This means that when the docker client specifies bind mount locations, the daemon (on the host) only understands them as paths on the host filesystem, not within the job container's filesystem. Therefore, the mounts won't work how you expect in this scenario.

Instead, you want to make sure you're using the docker daemon provided by the `docker:dind` service container. To do this, you can add the following environment variables to your job (or runner configuration):

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

You should also remove the docker socket mount from the `volumes` setting in your runner configuration.

This will ensure you are using the `docker:dind` service container as your docker daemon and bind mounts specified in your `docker-compose.yml` file will work as expected when communicating with the 'remote' daemon (the service container) over TCP.

---

Note: this configures communication without TLS. See the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled-in-the-docker-executor) for more information about other ways to configure dind using TLS.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using a Bind Mount instead of a Docker volume you need to make sure the correct permissions.

In this can you are mounting `./service/src/main/resources/graphql` so check that you have the right permissions.

For a quick and dirty check run the following:

```bash
find ./service/src/main/resources/graphql -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./service/src/main/resources/graphql -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

Note, you may want to further review these permissions to be as secure as possible.

Also it would be safer to use absolute paths insetad of relative paths (Eg `/home/someuser/service/src/main/resources/graphql`)

Comment: hi.. I did `chmod -R 777 ....` on that folder ... I can see it's now rwx for all .. but still no luck :-/

Comment: @Mr.P If you docker inspect the container are the mappings correct? also did you try using the full path instead of relative path?

Comment: I have absolute path .. how do I do the docker inspect?? Can't seem to be able to figure out :-/

Comment: `docker inspect container-name`